# Bootstrap em modelo de regressão linear - Calcular importância de variáveis

Tags: r, estatística-bootstrap, caret

Estou calculando a importância de variáveis para regressão múltipla com a função `varImp` do pacote `caret`. Porém ao fazer pelo usando função e bootstrap não consigo recuperar os valores como consegui para R².

Como posso salvar os valores de importância de coeficientes em .csv, por exemplo?

Exemplo replicável:

```
library(boot)
library(caret)

imp_lm <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices,] 

  fit.all <- lm(d$mpg~.,data=d)
  return(varImp(fit.all, scale = FALSE))
}

results <- boot(data=mtcars, statistic=imp_lm, R=10)
```

> **Error in t.star[r, ] <- res[[r]] : 
>    incorrect number of subscripts on matrix**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note que no help da função `boot`, o argumento `statistic` tem a seguinte descrição (grifos meus):

> A function which when applied to data returns a **vector** containing the statistic(s) of interest.

Ao rodarmos a função `varImp`, obtemos o seguinte:

```
fit.all <- lm(mpg ~ ., data=mtcars)
resultado <- varImp(fit.all, scale = FALSE)
is.data.frame(resultado)
## [1] TRUE
```

Portanto, o resultado da tua função `imp_lm` retorna um data frame, pois a função `varImp` retorna um data frame. Uma maneira de contornar isso é alterar a tua função, colocando `return(varImp(fit.all, scale = FALSE)[, 1])` ao final e, assim, extraindo a primeira coluna do resultado que calcula a importância das variáveis:

```
imp_lm <- function(data, indices) {
  d <- data[indices, ] 

  fit.all <- lm(mpg ~ ., data=d)
  return(varImp(fit.all, scale = FALSE)[, 1])
}

results <- boot(data=mtcars, statistic=imp_lm, R=10)
results

## ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
## 
## 
## Call:
## boot(data = mtcars, statistic = imp_lm, R = 10)
## 
## 
## Bootstrap Statistics :
##       original     bias    std. error
## t1*  0.1066392  0.8799646   0.7188905
## t2*  0.7467585 -0.1206878   0.4692999
## t3*  0.9868407 -0.1654184   0.5865589
## t4*  0.4813036  0.5936594   0.7967201
## t5*  1.9611887 -0.8193792   0.5743548
## t6*  1.1234133  0.2350501   0.7057048
## t7*  0.1509915  0.9933979   0.8952965
## t8*  1.2254035  0.5388327   1.3083746
## t9*  0.4389142  0.6839702   0.8997836
## t10* 0.2406258  0.9177274   1.3346145
```

Comment: Para o exemplo funcionou muito bem, estou assumindo que t1 - cyl, t2 - disp, t3 - hp... segue a ordem de disposição do dataframe (mtcars), isto é, é correto?

Quando aplico para meu conjunto de dados só funciona para menos de 30 variáveis, mais que isso o mesmo erro se mantém.

Comment: _Para o exemplo funcionou muito bem, estou assumindo que t1 - cyl, t2 - disp, t3 - hp... segue a ordem de disposição do dataframe (mtcars), isto é, é correto?_ Sim, isto está correto. Quanto à outra pergunta, ela foge do escopo da pergunta original. Até onde pude perceber, o problema proposto com o conjunto de dados de exemplo, foi resolvido de maneira correta.